# TypeError: mongoose.models is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am trying to build an e-commerce website, When i add the item inside itemList and run the next.js app i get this message

{ TypeError: mongoose.models is undefined

> 125 | export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", productSchema); }

The Model Code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true, 
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  images: [
    {
      public_id: {
        type: String,
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],


  stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },


});

export default mongoose.models.Product ||
  mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

Mongoose code :-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbConnect = () => {
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1) {
        return;
    }

    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI);

};

export default dbConnect;
```

Product Controller :-

```
import Product from "../models/product";

export const newProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  const product = await Product.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    product,
  });
};

export const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
  const products = await Product.find();
  res.status(200).json({
    products,
  });
};
```

I've been searching for 4 days but didn't find any solution, I tried to change `mongoose.models.Product`  to `mongoose.model.Product`  but still same problem and i tried many and many codes but still same

Next.js 13
Mongo DB 7